# Java Reflection Method Invocation with Unknown Bean Structure

Tags: java, reflection

I have written some code that feels like a hack.

```
private void handleSpecialCase(Method mvw, InterfacePersistenceBean pObj, AbstractBeanWrapper wrapper, String methodCore)
        throws TestStructureException
{
    try {

        Parameter p= getParameterByName(methodCore, this.PREFIX_SET,pObj);
        Method mp=null;
        try {
            mp = pObj.getClass().getMethod("set"+methodCore, new Class[]
                        { p.getType() });
        }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException e) {
            mp = pObj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("set"+methodCore, new Class[]
                        { p.getType() });
        }

        Method serviceMethod = beanByIdService.getClass().getMethod("get"+methodCore, new Class[]
                { java.lang.Long.class });

        InterfacePersistenceBean beanToSet=(InterfacePersistenceBean)serviceMethod.invoke(beanByIdService, mvw.invoke(wrapper));
        mp.setAccessible(true);
        mp.invoke(pObj, beanToSet);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        SS.getLogger().error(e.getMessage()+" "+e.getCause(),e);
        throw new TestStructureException(e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

- The inner try block (i.e., `getMethod()`) will get methods from superclasses, but will not get protected or private methods. If a method is protected it throws `NoSuchMethodException`.
- Hence the inner catch block uses `getDeclaredMethod()` which will get protected and private methods but throw `NoSuchMethodException` on superclass methods.
- A protected/private superclass method would always throw an exception here which is fine for my purposes but nonetheless inelegant.

Can someone suggest a more flexible, robust, and elegant approach (preferably without using annotations)?

Comment: so you need to invoke only the public getter methods hence preventing exceptions, right?

Comment: You shouldn't care about protected or private methods. In the general case you can't call them. So `getMethods()` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, conventionally true. But I was mapping from hibernate beans to thymeleaf view wrapper beans and back again. The hibernate bean had some setters that were protected (e.g., id). I didn't want to change them to public as the risk of programmer error elsewhere was too high.